# Scipt which will dump memory from DVR via Uboot with md command

Tags: shell-script, u-boot

So I have this DVR which is pretty locked so I need to use md command from U-boot to dump its memory,but the u-Boot reboots every ~15 second so I need to dump memory in chunks here is mine shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Replace with the actual serial port of your device (e.g., /dev/ttyACM0)
set serial_port "/dev/ttyACM0"

# Replace with the starting memory address
set start_address 0xe1000000

# Replace with the size of each chunk
set chunk_size 0x3E00

# Replace with the target address to stop at
set stop_address 0xE100BA00

# Open a connection to the serial port
spawn cu -l $serial_port -s 115200

# Expect the message to stop autoboot
expect "Hit any key to stop autoboot:"
send "\r"
#after 2000
# Set the initial address
set current_address $start_address

# Dump memory in chunks
while {$current_address < $stop_address} {
    # Send the md command to the bootloader for the current chunk
    send "md $current_address $chunk_size\r"

    # Wait for the bootloader's response
    expect "Hit any key to stop autoboot:"
    send "\r"

    # Send any key to continue (press Enter)
    send "\r"
    # Update the current address for the next chunk
    set current_address [expr {$current_address + $chunk_size}]
}

# Close the connection
send "\x03"  ;# Send Ctrl+C to stop autoboot if needed
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

So on first power it does print content of first chunk from memory but after reboots the device boots up sending "\r" after expect "Hit any key to stop autoboot:" does not work and I don't know why, any suggestion tnx ?